# Haskell sine and cosine functions not working

Tags: haskell, ghci, pi, trigonometry

Okay, this is a pretty weird problem.

The built-in Haskell sine function (sin) does not seem to work.

`sin 0` gives, correctly, `0`.

`sin pi` gives, for whatever reason, `1.2246467991473532e-16`

These are using the built in prelude functions. I simply start up ghci (the Haskell interpreter), and type in `sin pi` and get the wrong answer.

Also, `cos (pi/2)` gives `6.123233995736766e-17`

Any ideas why this might be? It looks like the build in functions are simply wrong.. which seems extremely unlikely seeing how mathematically-oriented the Haskell standard library is.

edit: Heh, I just simply overlooked the e-16.. I guess that's what I get for coding late at night. Thanks anyhow everyone!

Comment: Perhaps you should try `1 + sin pi` so you can see how close it actually is to the right answer.

Comment: You can also install the numbers package and use the type `Data.Number.CReal.CReal` instead of `Double`.  It's slow and accurate.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is Matlab

```
>> sin(pi)
ans =
  1.2246e-016
```

And here's Python

```
>>> from math import sin, pi
>>> sin(pi)
1.2246467991473532e-16
```

You're running into the limits of floating point precision. I recommend having a read of [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

---

The `e` at the end of these numbers indicates that they're in (a compact form of) [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), and stands for "× 10^".  For instance, in this notation, `2e3` corresponds to 2 × 10<sup>3</sup> = 2000.  Here, you have a number that's multiplied by 10<sup>-16</sup>, which is tiny; written out in full,  `1.2246467991473532e-16` = 0.00000000000000012246467991473532, so the amount of error is very small.

---

If you want accurate real-number computations in Haskell, you can use the `CReal` package as follows.

```
>>> import Data.Number.CReal
>>> sin (0.0  :: CReal)
0.0
>>> sin (pi   :: CReal)
0.0
>>> cos (pi/2 :: CReal)
0.0
```

This works because "under the hood" a `CReal` is a function `Int -> Integer`. Given a number of digits `d` to output, the function produces the `Integer` that, when divided by `10^d`, would give the real number correct to `d` decimal places.

Comment: The real problem here is `pi` itself.

Comment: I understand about floating point precision, it just didn't occur to me since 1.2 is so far from 0. Do you know how, mathematically, this much error makes sense?

Comment: @Nathan The result is `1.22 * 10^(-16)` which is (relatively speaking) quite close to zero - it is roughly `0.000000000000000122`.

Comment: @Nathan did you see the `e-16` there? This means the result is very close to zero.

Comment: Haha yeah, I just realized that a little bit ago. Simply overlooked the e-16. That's what I get for coding late at night. Thanks for the clarification guys.

Comment: Hopefully this isn't too off-topic, but why don't language just hard code `sin(pi) = 0`? It's not like that will ever change.

Answer (score 2):

The error in the double precision pi itself is -2.3846200000000026e-17, so losing another decimal in accuracy for a function like sin is not bad.