# sin function returning numbers outside of range [-1, 1]

Tags: haskell, trigonometry

I am working in Haskell and have had an error where, for really large floats z, `sin(z)` returns some value outside of the range [-1, 1].

I'm learning Haskell for the first time, so I have had very little luck debugging and the program just crashes when sin(z) does return a value outside of the above range as sin(z) is an input into another function that only accepts values inside the range [-1, 1].

Additionally, I don't have access to the other function, I only can send in a value, but it keeps crashing when sin(z) returns a number either greater than 1 or less than -1.

Is there any way to figure out why sin(z) is doing this?

Comment: Can you give an example of such a `z` that produces this behavior?

Comment: I doubt that you're getting any values above 1 or below -1. But you may very well be getting NaNs. Check, and give us a concrete, complete example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `sin :: Double -> Double` function returns a number strictly between `-1` and `1` for all **finite** inputs, no matter how large.  In particular, for the largest representable finite positive double, it returns a value that's roughly 0.005:

```
> sin (1.7976931348623157E+308 :: Double)
4.961954789184062e-3
```

and for the largest representable finite negative double, it returns a value that's the negative of that:

```
> sin (-1.7976931348623157E+308 :: Double)
-4.961954789184062e-3
```

What's undoubtedly happening is that your input to `sin` has exceeded the finite range of `Double`.  For example, the following double isn't actually representable as a finite double and is "rounded" to infinity:

```
> 1.7976931348623159E+308 :: Double
Infinity
```

If you feed such an infinite value to `sin`, you get `NaN`:

```
> sin (1.7976931348623159E+308 :: Double)
NaN
```

which will undoubtedly cause problems when fed to a function expecting finite numbers between `-1` and `1`.  This can be "fixed" with `min`:

```
> min (sin (1.7976931348623159E+308 :: Double)) 1
1.0
```

but this fix is largely useless because you have a much bigger problem going on.

For numbers this large, the precision of a `Double` is on the order of plus or minus 1e292.  That is, two "adjacent" representable finite doubles of this size are about 1e292 apart and the `sin` of two such numbers might as well be random numbers between `-1` and `1`, completely unrelated to any calculation you're trying to complete.  Whatever you're trying to do with these numbers can't possibly be working as you intend.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like this is a floating point error; see [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566768/haskell-sine-and-cosine-functions-not-working). So for very large values, the `sin` function is returning a value slightly above 1, due to rounding errors.

To solve your problem, I would cap the return value at 1. Specifically, return the `min 1 (sin z)` instead of just the `sin z` directly.

Edit: replaced `max` with `min`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something in that post, but I don't see any values above 1. I see values that are very, very small (close to zero) like `1.2246467991473532e-16`, but I don't see any that are above 1.

Comment: ...and I doubt that there are `Double` values whose sine is slightly above 1. So `max` is unlikely do be any use here. If you disagree, give an example.

Comment: You should use `min` here, otherwise it will return a value *at least* one.

Comment: You're both right! Thank you guys for your help :)

Comment: This solution sounds dangerous; there's no reason to believe capping at 1 is meaningful. But it doesn't address the issue anyhow: We're yet to see an input where this alleged `> 1` output is produced. As an "accepted answer" this is really misleading.